# Always center Imageview in Scrollview

Tags: android

I have a scrollview in my activity_main with a constrained layout inside. Above that I want to place an Imageview which is always centered on the current visible screen.
My XML looks like this:

```
<ScrollView>
  <ConstraintLayout>
     <ImageButton>
     <ImageButton>
     <ImageButton>
     <ImageButton>
     <ImageButton>
     <ImageButton>
     <ImageView> <------- This should be always centered in the view  
  </ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: leftToLeft of parent rightToRight of parent

Comment: @noev Thanks, but I want to center the view horicontally and vertically.